# keeping an input focused with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, input

I have an input box that shrinks when not in focus (as seen here http://jsfiddle.net/5Lc5w).
As a consequence of this, when the user submits something, the box immediately shrinks.
I've tried `focus()` which doesn't appear to work and I've tried changing the style attributes but of course this doesn't (can't) change the pseudo class.

Is there a way to solve this using Javascript?

Comment: I think you it will be shrink on when user type some character not when focus

Comment: Please tell do you want like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`this`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/5Lc5w/2/), this is helpful for you.

JS

```
   $('#userIn').keyup(function(){
   if($(this).val()!='')
        $(this).addClass('slide');
   else
        $(this).removeClass('slide');        
   });
```

Change css name `input:focus`  with `.slide`

CSS

```
.slide
{
   border: 1px solid blue;
   transition:.3s;
  -webkit-transition:.3s;
   width:160px;
}
```

Comment: not what I was after, but that's really nice actually (i may end up using that). what I meant was having the input slide open when clicked and staying open even after submit was pressed. thank you for your answer.

Comment: Where is submit lying?

Comment: *the ► symbol rather.

Comment: Ok you say it will slide only ► symol will click, not when input pass in textbox

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `min-width` to the CSS after the focus event, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#userIn').focus(function () {

        $(this).css({'min-width':200}); 
    });
});
```

I'm using jQuery for simplicity but you can do without if you need to. Here's the updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lc5w/1/).

Comment: +1 I really like this approach too, but I'm accepting Subhash's answer as he kept the shrink feature.

Comment: Just for info, you can also look into the .blur() function that captures the lost focus event, which would be helpful if you wanted to reshrink the box on unfocus. BTW, reshrinking isn't what you had asked for but I can see how it can be helpful from a design perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I would just adjust the width, like so

```
document.getElementById('userIn').style.width = '160px';
```

[Reference](http://jsfiddle.net/YK2QT/)

---

You didn't post **why** you wanted it enlarged, so this is all I can suggest.